# jQuery: add new class name inside attribute class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a new class name inside the related attribute class in order to validate a specific input field.
When a certain option of a select has been selected then I need to add a new class name.
The script below works and actually the new class is added as expected, but the validate.js does not recognize the class name **required-field**.
 If add the class name **required-field** manuallay the validate.js file recognizes it.

```
if(val == 1) {
$('#firstname').addClass('required-field');
}

<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="form-control required-field" />
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Show us your `validate.js` code

Comment: Presumably `validate.js` searches for elements at initialisation time and not after you've modified the element.

Comment: There are 100s of libraries for validation, what one are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the plugin validate.js takes care of a new rule added dynamically you need to do:

```
        if (val == 1) {
            $("#firstname").rules("add", "required");
        } else {
            $("#firstname").rules("remove", "required");
        }
```

For details refer to [Read, add and remove rules for an element](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/)